# Grid view page number spacing?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a Grid View shown below (bottom code):

```
      <asp:BoundField DataField="UID" HeaderText="UID" SortExpression="UID"
                      ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
          <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
      </asp:BoundField>
  </Columns>
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left"  />
  <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
</asp:GridView>
```

In pager style i have not used any class ...but my page numbers appear too much spacious.
I need it together in the middle of the gridview. But it appears to be one at left(Page 1) and after a big space one at center (Page 2).

Can someone help to make my page numbers together in the center of grid view?

PS: Grid View not lies in a `<div>` or `<table>`

but there is a `<div>` and `<table>` in my webpage at bottom and top of the grid view

Answer (score 4):

You've set the HorizonalAlignment of the PagerStyle property to Left.  Change it to "Center". You can read more about the PagerStyle property here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagerstyle.aspx

The following will center the page numbers in your GridView:

```
<PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to increase the space between the Gridview page numbers, add the following style in your page :

```
          .cssPager td
        {
              padding-left: 4px;     
              padding-right: 4px;    
          }
    </style>
```

And reference this style inside your GridView Pager Style :

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="cssPager" />
```

Source : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=244